# Missing argument 4 for wp_insert_term()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create category from **WordPress plugin**. Here is my code:

```
$id = wp_create_category('Category_name', 2);
```

But i am getting this
 error:

> **Missing argument 4 for wp_insert_term(), called in taxonomy.php on line 144 and defined in taxonomy.php on line 2226**

But i am not using function `wp_insert_term()` anywhere. Please help me. What i am doing wrong? is there anything extra which i have to do in plugin to make it working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe of the functions you use uses `wp_insert_term()`

Comment: can you tell me which plugin ?

Comment: @rajnikfaldu i am creating custom plugin.

Comment: which version of wordpress are you using?

Comment: @Cristian i am using 4.6.1 version

Comment: Is there a category in your WP DB that has the ID 2?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you're trying to add a category with a parent that does not exist

Comment: before adding your cat make sure the parent, that in this case is 2, exists

Comment: 2 is your parent cat id so please check its exit ..otherwise 2 replace with 0

Comment: @Cristian yes that category is exists and i have also tried with 0 but same issue arrived.

Comment: the docs say that you can actually call the function just with the name parameter try that one and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use wp_insert_category as wp_create_category is just a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Passing a category ID means you're trying to create a child category, so make sure that a category with and ID of `2` exists.
2. If you do have a category with an ID of `2`, try omitting that param and seeing what happens. If your still getting an error after that, check what version of PHP you are using and update it.
3. If you're making a plugin to add a category to the database you will be better off using [wp_insert_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category) as it gives you more control.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have also tried with parentid 0 and also tried wp_insert_category()  but same issue